# IndexedDB or SQLite for internal database developing on Intel XDK

Tags: sqlite, indexeddb, intel-xdk

I already have the webapp which will be convert to mobile app through Intel XDK but I dont know what option to choose regarding databases, I wanted to learn more about SQLite for this but I saw in some articles that SQLite is deprecated for this goal, am I wrong?

On the other hand is IndexedDB which I just read about today

I can´t find fresh info about this doubt, can you advice me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `IndexedDB` rather than `SQLite`. I found it difficult to find a proper plugin for `SQLite` which is still supported and has some useful documentation.

I found a excellent plugin with excellent documentation also and support from the author for `IndexedDB`. It is called [Dexie](http://dexie.org/) and is described as a *A Minimalistic Wrapper for IndexedDB*. It also has a Github page which is located [here](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/wiki/Getting-started).

**Example**

Some examples taken from their site.

Database Connection:

```
/*
|----------------------------|
| Make a database connection |
|----------------------------|
*/

var db = new Dexie('MyDatabase');

// Define a schema
db.version(1).stores({
    friends: 'name, age'
});


// Open the database
db.open().catch(function(error) {
    alert('Uh oh : ' + error);
});
```

Executing Queries:

```
/*
|-----------------------|
| Then run some queries |
|-----------------------|
*/

// Find some old friends
db.friends
    .where('age')
    .above(75)
    .each (function (friend) {
        console.log (friend.name);
    });

// or make a new one
db.friends.add({
    name: 'Camilla',
    age: 25
});
```